# How can I manually create a signature for record editing?

Tags: python, web2py

The `SQLFORM.grid` method generates an *Edit* button with the following generic URL:

```
a/c/f/table/record_id?_signature=md5
```

(Where a=application, c=controller and f=function.)

How can I obtain, given the record id, such URL (or at least the `_signature` argument) so I can place an *Edit* button somewhere else in my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should generate the proper URL:

```
URL('a', 'c', 'f', args=['table', record_id], user_signature=True, hash_vars=False)
```

In this case, `hash_vars=False` isn't strictly necessary, as there are no URL variables, but just in case...